# Summernote createRange with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

Some text in my summernote editor contains HTML. I want to get the user selected text, exactly as it is in the editor.

All the answers I've seen so far tell me to use this

```
$('#summernote').summernote('createRange').toString()
```

But it strips all the existing HTML from the selection. This:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code')
```

Returns all the text, with HTML, but not regarding the user selected text.

Is there a way to get the user selected text with all HTML and formatting in summernote?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution - output in `html` variable.

```js
var range = $('#summernote').summernote('createRange');
var nodes = range.nodes();
var div = document.createElement('div');
for (i=0; i<nodes.length; ++i) {
    div.appendChild(nodes[i].cloneNode(true));
}
var html = div.innerHTML;
```