# Summernote - selected html

Tags: html, range, selection, summernote

I am using the summernote editor and I am curious if it is possible to get the html code corresponding to the selected text in the editor.

This:

`$('#summernote').summernote('createRange').toString()`

only gives me a text without any html code.

This:

`$('#summernote').summernote('code')`

returns all the text, with HTML, but not regarding the user selected text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203772/summernote-createrange-with-html

Comment: @ThomasSambugaro it's not working for me. I get error on `range.nodes()`